# nginx+nodejs+socket.io ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, connection-timeout

I almost tried any solution I can find in forums and blogs but I have no luck that's why I'm asking for any help right now.

Here's the situation, I am currently using Ubuntu and I'm running 2 sockets in it before which running perfectly but when I tried to add another 1 more socket the problem arise (The ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

Here is my set up on NGINX for my third socket

```
upstream stream {
    server localhost:3210;
}

server {
  location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://stream;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

This is the same exact nginx setup that I have had with my first 2 app, that's why I'm having a hard time to debug it, also with the nodejs server.

```
http.listen(3210, function(){
  console.log('Listening on Port 3210');
});
```

and on front-end

```
var socket = io.connect('http://testapp.com:3210');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems incorrect:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://testapp.com:3210');
```

Port 3210 is what Express is listening on, and given that you're proxying using Nginx I'd expect that the client should connect to Nginx, not Express:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://testapp.com');
```

(provided that Nginx is running on port 80)

Comment: Yes http://testapp.com is running on port 80. damn, it eats lot of my time debugging this one. I'm just confused because my other two apps are running with the same implementation. Thank you so much @robertklep